# Run a Script with Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script from the book Data Science at Command Line, Jeroen Janssens like this

```
curl -s http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/76/pg76.txt |
 tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -oE '\w+' | sort |
 uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

and saved it as top-world-1.sh

From terminal of Ubuntu 15.10 64bit, I put a command  `./top-words-1.sh` and I got output likes

```
./top-words-1.sh: line 1: $'\r': command not found
./top-words-1.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
```

At once, I guessed that was caused by multiple line and I remove '\n' places to make a sentence like this

```
curl -s http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/76/pg76.txt |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -oE '\w+' | sort |uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

But I got

```
: invalid number of lines
```

I'm totally new in programming bash script. Could you please give me any advices? Thanks in advance

Following comments below, I have:

- checked permission

[image]

- added `#!/bin/bash` at the top of file and got output `bash: ./top-words-1.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
- run with sudo

Comment: What kind of editor are you using to create your top-words-1.sh file? The errors suggest it is saving with DOS-style line endings: make sure you are using an editor that saves with Unix-style endings. You should also add a `#!/bin/bash` shebang at the top of the file to ensure it is run as a bash script.

Comment: Hi, I use nano editor. I have add `#!/bin/bash' at top of file and when I ran it, I showed "bash: ./top-words-1.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory".  I have check different script, they work in stead of this one. I also check execute permission, permission is correct

Comment: Create an entirely new script, don't copy-paste text and see what happens. Also, try running `dos2unix` on the script that has the error.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Just copy the text, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `dos2unix` command to solve my problem. Thank @muru for your comment. The reason is explained by @steeldriver

Answer (score 1):

It does work for me. Try:

```
cat > script.sh <<EOF
#! /bin/bash
 curl -s http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/76/pg76.txt |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -oE '\w+' | sort |uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10
EOF
 chmod +x script.sh
 ./script.sh
```

And it gives me the right answer. Make sure you are not adding any extra (hidden) characters to the file. You can also copy/paste the command into the shell to make sure it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

either run your script with the command: `bash ./scriptname` , or `chmod +x script` then: `./scriptname`

command not found probably means its not executable.

Comment: Sadly, I doesn't work.